# Unwrapping optionals

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite, swift, option-type

I have two values in an sql lite database which I am trying to print (I am following a tutorial on core data)

```
    var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Users");
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false;
    var results = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil);


    if(results?.count > 0){
        for result:AnyObject in results! {
            println(result.password!);
            println(result.name!);
        }
    }else{
        println("No results found");
    }
```

Doing the following prints the output seen below

```
Optional("pass")
Ricki
```

However, If i modify the

> result.password

To be the following

```
 println(result.password! as String!);
```

Then i get the output as follows;

```
pass
Ricki
```

Why do i need to do this for one column in the database for it to print without the optional but not for the other?

Thanks

Comment: Why you use `AnyObject` instead of `Users` when going through results? Please show the `name` and `password` are declared on `Users`.

Comment: In your object model have you unticked the optional checkbox for the `name` property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not cast as Anyobject, better Cast als NSObject Array.

Like:

```
var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Users");
request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false;
var users = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil) as [Users]

If users.count > 0 {

    for user in users  {

        println(user.password);
        println(user.name);
    }

}
```

The reason why one if your values might need an ! could be that you have unchecked the "Optional Checkbox" in your Core Data

[image]